# Is char variable always represented as dereferenced char*[2] with {'x',\0}?

Tags: c++, c, c++11, casting, char

I tried this method to convert a char digit to an integer digit ('3'->3) and it seems to work.

```
char c='x';
int i=atoi(&c);
```

My question is, will this always work?

Is there always a NULL character after the first character?

There is another way to do this using implicit typecast, but I am not sure it is a good practice. Actually, I am pretty surprised there are no warnings even using -Wall and -Wextra.

```
int i = c - '0';
```

Note I am using GCC 4.8.2 and MinGW.

Comment: This is pretty much undefined behaviour. It works because probably out of bounds accessed memory has value 0.

Comment: For the second case, C and C++ [guarantees the order of  digit characters](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32586834/1708801)

Comment: You are confusing strings and chars. A `char` is always a single character.

Comment: Please pick one of C and C++.

Comment: @FUZxxl Is there a difference? I am interested in both.

Comment: @Slazer There might be, I don't know. Point is, asking about “something in C/C++” is not much different from “something in Ada/Pascal/PHP.” Few people are knowledgeable about tiny language details in *both* of C and C++, so policy is that you ask a question only for one language at a time. If you are interested in an answer for both, then ask two questions, you can refer to the first one in your second.

Comment: I am not a downvoter but as the question reads now, it sure seems like a C question. Are you compiling as C++? If so you should note that but why add the C tag? Are you compiling for both, if so you should also specify that in your question. There are cases where the answer in C and C++ will be very different which can lead to some confusing answers. Although I don't know if I agree with @FUZxxl that this particular question should be two questions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This compiles but it's undefined behavior.

A `char` is just a character. No null byte following. `std::atoi` expects a null byte, though, so invoking `std::atoi(&c)` compiles but yields undefined behavior. This line,

```
int i = std::atoi("x");
```

is well-defined, though, because the string `"x"` is a `char[2]` and null-terminated.

```
int i = c - '0';
```

is alright because<sup>1</sup> the [C++11 standard](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32586834/1708801) and the [C99 standard](https://stackoverflow.com/q/781668/1708801)<sup>2</sup> guarantee the order of character digits.

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> as @ShafikYaghmour noted in the comments to your question</sub>

<sub><sup>2</sup> Thanks to @ShafikYaghmour again!</sub>

Comment: @Slazer That's undefined behaviour. It may work, but it can also make dæmons fly out of your nose.

Comment: @Slazer Ah, I see, that's what you mean. Will clarify that.

Comment: Well it may work and it works in my case. So the statement "This will not work at all" is false. I understand what undefined behaviour is, though.

Comment: @Slazer OK, fixed it.

Comment: Its quite ridiculous there is no such function is C/C++ library. The stoi() mentioned by David Haim is perfect, except only for strings. It even has exceptions!

Comment: The [C version of the question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/781668/1708801) on order of digits.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour Thank you very much!

Comment: I just wonder how come that there is no warning because of the typecast (even with -Wall and -Wextra)? Because my first try was simply write {char c; int i=c;} which would give me ASCII values instead of digits. A warning would definitely be in order here.

Answer (score 1):

`atoi` expects null terminated C-string.

since you didn't provide it (you provided a pointer to character) this is undefined behaviour.

for the second line of code - this generally works if you can guarantee that the character is indeed a digit. for example , the character `#` will yield a result but may not the result you'd expect.

some solution is to use `std::stoi`:

```
try{ int x = std::stoi(std::string() + c) } catch(...) {/*handle*/}
```

Comment: Using a string seems to me too heavy for such a simple task. The exception functionality seems nice, though.

Answer (score 0):

This will work as long as next to the memory space where c is allocated is a \0. In other words, it's just luck. You should use `int i = c - '0'`

But be aware that every character will be mapped to int (f.e. `int i = 'a' - '0'`)

To avoid this you could do something like:

```
int i = c=>'0' && c<='9' ? c-'0' : -1; //-1 represents not valid values
```

Comment: Most likely because you claimed that an undefined program will work. The actual value (possibly) stored in `&c + 1` doesn't matter, as accessing it has undefined behaviour.

Comment: But it's the explanation of why his program worked (at least when OP tested it). Undefined behaviour != not working, in the best case it won't work, in the worst it will work when you test it and crash later (Like this)